# Enumerable column in simple dataset

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have created my first dataset, which is divided into 3 smaller datasets. Main data is 1000 rows about cars, columns: model,year,mileage,price. Column "model" is enumerable (FiestaSedan,Super,Transit) and next 3 columns are numerical. 
Other 3 dataset haven't first column and are one dataset for model. Price is function(model,year,mileage) without noise. For these 3 smaller datasets training is OK (except that in optimal case maybe error should be almost zero?).
DAtasets are in Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrzejbo/car-price-synthesized
and notebook is https://www.kaggle.com/code/andrzejbo/notebook15924a2f77, which contain:

```
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tensorflow as tf # for processing data as tensors
import seaborn as sns # to plot data
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization, Dense, InputLayer # the layer which outputs normalized data
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError, MeanAbsoluteError, Huber
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))



df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/car-price-synthesized/FiestaSedan.csv')

tensor_data = tf.constant(df)
tensor_data = tf.random.shuffle(tensor_data)

X, y = tensor_data[:, 0:2], tensor_data[:, 2:]
X_train, y_train = X[:int(0.8 * len(df))], y[:int(0.8 * len(df))]
X_val, y_val = X[int(0.8 * len(df)):int(0.9 * len(df))], y[int(0.8 * len(df)):int(0.9 * len(df))]
X_test, y_test = X[int(0.9 * len(df)):], y[int(0.9 * len(df)):]

normalizer = Normalization()
normalizer.adapt(X_train)
normalized = normalizer(X_train)



model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(normalizer)
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
              loss=MeanAbsoluteError(),
              metrics=RootMeanSquaredError())

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=100)



n = len(history.history['loss'])
sns.lineplot(x=range(n), y=history.history['root_mean_squared_error'])
sns.lineplot(x=range(n), y=history.history['val_root_mean_squared_error'])
```

How can I with enumerated column, with file FordPrices.csv to training find 3 differ functions for 3 differ models?